# How to get the ios device logs programatically

Tags: ios, logging, console

I want to retrieve the system logs which will have the information about sip (Session Initiate Protocol), this protocol has the information about signalling of audio/video call and generated by the system (framework) logs and RIL(Radio interface Layer) logs. How to get the Ios system logs?

I tried many resource but nothing found.

Comment: I searched and found lots of resources and answers on the subject. Please write down what you have tried and what's not working. This is described in the SO rules.